# SELECT DISTINCT in Scala slick

Tags: scala, slick

I am using Slick 1, and I have to be able to apply a filter in a query to lookup all entities that match a condition in a related table.

This example using the Slick documentation shows what I am trying to do (this is a contrived example that is close to my situation).

Here, I want all coffees that are provided by suppliers on the west coast.  I want the Coffee only, I am only interested in navigating to Suppliers to apply the filter:

```
val westCoast = Seq("CA", "OR", "WA")
val implicitInnerJoin = for {
  c <- Coffees
  s <- Suppliers if c.supID === s.id && s.state inSet westCoast
} yield c
```

This works ok, but it will duplicate Coffees if there is more than one match in the Suppliers table.

The obvious workaround is in normal SQL to do a SELECT DISTINCT; however, I cannot find a way to do that here.

You could in theory do a:

```
query.list.distinct
```

After the results are already returned; however, I have also implemented PAGING support, so you wouldn't want to process the results once the already come back from the database.  Here is the paging support:

```
query.drop(offset).take(limit).list
```

So, in a nutshell, I *need* a way to specify SELECT DISTINCT in my query that goes out.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As a work around you can try to use groupBy:

```
query.groupBy(x=>x).map(_._1)
```

It should have the same semantics as distinct, but I'm not sure about performance.

Comment: Hey, this one worked!  I am not exactly sure why, I haven't done more of a deep dive, but I needed a quick fix.

Comment: For some reason, this gives me a `scala.TupleN` instead of `XxxRow` entity, with `ClassCastException` thrown.

Comment: Keep in mind that this will mess your result if you had some sorting in `query`.

Answer (score 22):

With slick 3.1.0 you can use `distinct` and `distinctOn` functions ([Slick 3.1.0 release notes](http://slick.typesafe.com/news/2015/10/09/slick-3.1.0-released.html)). For example:

```
val westCoast = Seq("CA", "OR", "WA")
val implicitInnerJoin = for {
  c <- Coffees
  s <- Suppliers if c.supID === s.id && s.state inSet westCoast
} yield c

db.run(implicitInnerJoin.distinctOn(_.name).result)
```

**Update**
Finally bug related to `distinctOn` was resolved in [slick 3.3.3](https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/2097)

Comment: FWIW, there seems to be [a bug with distinctOn](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1712) at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this implemented yet. See https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/96

Answer (score 2):

For distinct on multiple columns coffee.name and coffee.price:

```
val westCoast = Seq("CA", "OR", "WA")
val implicitInnerJoin = for {
  c <- Coffees
  s <- Suppliers if c.supID === s.id && s.state inSet westCoast
} yield c

db.run(implicitInnerJoin.map(f => (f.name, f.price, f.state)).distinctOn(p => (p._1, p._2)).result)
```

Comment: It needs to be it the **specific order** you described - i.e. `map(a => (a.id, a.name)).disctinctOn(a => (a._1, a._2))`  or one gets `slick key not found: s2` runtime exception. Doing `distinctOn(a => (a.id, a.name))` won't work