# Picking max item by column from group by in Slick 3.x

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala, slick

I'm trying to write a Slick query to find the "max" element within a group and then continue querying based on that result, however I'm getting a massive error when I try what I thought was the obvious way:

```
val articlesByUniqueLink = for {
  (link, groupedArticles) <- historicArticles.groupBy(_.link)
  latestPerLink <- groupedArticles.sortBy(_.pubDate.desc).take(1)
} yield latestPerLink
```

Since this doesn't seem to work, I'm wondering if there's some other way to find the "latest" element out of "groupedArticles" above, assuming these come from an Articles table with a pubDate Timestamp and a link that can be duplicated. I'm effectively looking for `HAVING articles.pub_date = max(articles.pub_date)`.

The other equivalent way to express it yields the same result:

```
val articlesByUniqueLink = for {
  (link, groupedArticles) <- historicArticles.groupBy(_.link)
  latestPerLink <- groupedArticles.filter(_.pubDate === groupedArticles.map(_.pubDate).max.get)
} yield latestPerLink
```

[SlickTreeException: Unreachable reference to s2 after resolving monadic joins + 50 lines of Slick node trees.

Comment: Which exact version of Slick are you using? Did you take a look at these bug reports? https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1316, https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/1513

Comment: Having a similar issue, did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

The best way I found to get max or min or etc. per group in Slick is to use self join on grouping result:

```
val articlesByUniqueLink = for {
  (article, _) <- historicArticles join historicArticles.groupBy(_.link)
      .map({case (link, group) => (link, group.map(_.pubDate).max)})
          on ((article, tuple) => article.link === tuple._1 && 
              article.pubDate === tuple._2)
} yield article
```

If there is possible to produce duplicates with `on` condition, just drop duplicates like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256768/select-distinct-in-scala-slick) after.